# How to prove such a lemma in labeled transition system in Isablle

Tags: isabelle

I have defined such a labled transition system as below, and a function to judge given a list whether it could be reached.

```
type_synonym ('q,'a) LTS = "('q * 'a set * 'q) set"


primrec LTS_is_reachable :: "('q, 'a) LTS \<Rightarrow> 'q \<Rightarrow> 'a list \<Rightarrow> 'q \<Rightarrow> bool" where
   "LTS_is_reachable \<Delta> q [] q' = (q = q')"|
"LTS_is_reachable \<Delta> q (a # w) q' =
      (\<exists>q'' \<sigma>. a \<in> \<sigma> \<and> (q, \<sigma>, q'') \<in> \<Delta> \<and> LTS_is_reachable \<Delta> q'' w q')"
```

But the problem is that i don't know how to prove below lemma.

```
lemma "LTS_is_reachable {([], {v}, [v])} [] x [v] \<Longrightarrow> x = [v]"
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the definition you have to make a case distinction on `x` to make the definition patterns appear:

```
lemma "LTS_is_reachable {([], {v}, [v])} [] x [v] ⟹ x = [v]"
  apply (cases x; cases ‹tl x›)
   apply auto
  done
```

EDIT: as a side remark, it feels more natural to me to first define a function returning the set of all reachable states and then check if v is with the set. I expect this version to be easier to reason with.

Comment: Can you help me define the function of this reachable set

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, but i don't know how to prove lemma "x ∈ v ⟹ LTS_is_reachable {([], v, [x])} [] xa [x] ⟹ xa = [x]"

Comment: @for your second question: nitpick finds a counterexample (and any proof attempt should bring you to a similar problem). For the other question: I would have gone along `primrec LTS_is_reachable_set :: "('q, 'a) LTS ⇒ 'q ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'q set" where
   "LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q [] = {q}"|
"LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q (a # w) =
    (⋃((λ(q, σ, q''). LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q'' w) ` Δ))"` (although this definition is certainly wrong as the `a \in \sigma` condition is missing, but easy to fix)

Comment: Would you like to help my another problem, that will be much helpful. This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72162236/one-more-question-on-the-proof-of-labeled-transition-system-in-isabelle ,