# One more question on the proof of labeled transition system in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

```
type_synonym ('q,'a) LTS = "('q * 'a set * 'q) set"

primrec LTS_is_reachable :: "('q, 'a) LTS \<Rightarrow> 'q \<Rightarrow> 'a list \<Rightarrow> 'q \<Rightarrow> bool" where
   "LTS_is_reachable \<Delta> q [] q' = (q = q')"|
   "LTS_is_reachable \<Delta> q (a # w) q' =
      (\<exists>q'' \<sigma>. a \<in> \<sigma> \<and> (q, \<sigma>, q'') \<in> \<Delta> \<and> LTS_is_reachable \<Delta> q'' w q')"

lemma subLTSlemma:"LTS_is_reachable l1 q x y \<Longrightarrow> LTS_is_reachable (l1 \<union> l2) q x
```

If the transition system L1 satisfies the reachability of X, then whether the transition system containing L1 also satisfies this property. I met some difficulties in proving this lemma. Please help me prove it. Isar will be better.

Comment: Without trying to even look at the proof: generalize over q.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this proof, how to generalize it.

Comment: `apply (induction x arbitrary: q)`. Did you try to prove the lemma on paper?

Comment: Actually it's a urgent work, I just prove it straight in isabelle. Need I prove it on paper first?

Comment: I already gave you the solution: `by apply (induction x arbitrary: q) auto`. However, if you have no idea how to prove something of paper, you have no chance to do in Isabelle. (And the fact that the `arbitrary` is missing is part of the things that are obvious if you have an intuition how to do it on paper).

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, but it seems that reading Isabelle's tutorial did not help me improve my theorem proving ability on paper. What should I do